# Sony SPRESENSE Arduino Libraryでのボード定義での設定切替方法

Tags: spresense, arduino

SPRESENSEで使うために既存のライブラリを修正しています。
SPRESENSEであることを判別するために、ボード定義のdefineで設定を切替をしようとしているのですが、うまく行きません。
実際に試した記述は以下です。

```
#if defined (ESP32)
  #include "Processors/xxx.h"
#elif defined (ESP8266)
  #include "Processors/xxx.h"
#elif defined (SPRESENSE)
  #include "Processors/SPRESENSE.h"
#else
  #include "Processors/Generic.h"
#endif
```

SPRESENSEのボードを選択した際にdefinedとなるプロセッサタイプを教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ビルドログをみると -DARDUINO_ARCH_SPRESENSE が定義されており、いくつかのライブラリではこのdefineを使って識別しているようです。(-DSPRESENSE という定義があっても良いような気がしますが...)

```
#if defined (ESP32)
  #include "Processors/xxx.h"
#elif defined (ESP8266)
  #include "Processors/xxx.h"
#elif defined (ARDUINO_ARCH_SPRESENSE)
  #include "Processors/SPRESENSE.h"
#else
  #include "Processors/Generic.h"
#endif
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます。